# Two-level subscript

Tags: subscripts

I need an equation of the type

```
\begin{equation*}
    lim_{Z=X-Y,X,Y>0}
\end{equation*}
```

which results in a long subscript that is ugly. How can I write this so that the superscript has two levels, with Z=X-Y on the top level and X,Y>0 on the bottom level?

Comment: Surely a duplicate, but `\lim_{\substack{z=x-y\\x,y>0}}` will do. It needs `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: @egreg yes, it is a duplicate. Apologies all...

Comment: No need to apologize! 